# RPC call to external server

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am a new bie on GWT, I wrote an application on `abc.com`, I have another application i.e. `xyz.com`, `xyz.com?id=1` provides me a data in `json` format, I was thinking to find a way that how to get that `json` file in `abc.com` via `RPC` call, because I have seen tutorials in which RPC calls are used to get data from its server. any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I am trying to implement [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/FAQ_Server#How_can_I_dynamically_fetch_JSON_feeds_from_other_web_domains?) in this [StockWatcher tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.1/tutorial/Xsite)

I changed my code slightly change to this

```
private static final String JSON_URL = "http://localhost/stockPrices.php?q=";
```

AND

```
 private void refreshWatchList() {
            if (stocks.size() == 0) {
                return;
            }

            String url = JSON_URL;

            // Append watch list stock symbols to query URL.
            Iterator iter = stocks.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                url += iter.next();
                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    url += "+";
                }
            }

            url = URL.encode(url);

            MyJSONUtility.makeJSONRequest(url, new JSONHandler() {

                @Override
                public void handleJSON(JavaScriptObject obj) {
                    if (obj == null) {
                        displayError("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
                        return;
                    }
                    updateTable(asArrayOfStockData(obj));
                }
            });


        }
```

before when I was requesting my url via `RequestBuilder` it was giving me an exception `Couldn't retrieve JSON` but now `JSON` is fetched and status code is 200 as I saw that in `firebug` but it is not updating on table. Kindly help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand the [Same Origin Policy](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/FAQ_Server#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) which explains how browsers implement a security model where JavaScript code running on a web page may not interact with any resource not originating from the same web site.

**While GWT's HTTP client and RPC call can only fetch data from the same site where your application was loaded**, you can get data from another server if it returns json in the right format. You must be interacting with a JSON service that can invoke user defined callback functions with the JSON data as argument.

Second, see [How to Fetch JSON DATA](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/FAQ_Server#How_can_I_dynamically_fetch_JSON_feeds_from_other_web_domains?)